# El depurador de Eclipse dejó de funcionar en un espacio de trabajo

Tags: java, eclipse, depuración, jboss

Tengo un servidor JBoss configurado en dos workspaces diferentes de eclipse con exactamente la misma configuración que consiste en

- Argumentos de programa: `--configuration=all --host=localhost -Djboss.server.base.url=file:/C:/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/`
- Argumentos de MV: `"-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 5.1" -server -Xms2g -Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\lib\endorsed"`

En un workspace me hace el debug en el eclipse sin problemas, pero en el otro, se nota lentitud al cargar y siempre se apaga sin mandar ningún mensaje de error tras unos 10 minutos mostrando como último en el log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address is 127.0.0.1:55200 (cluster=DefaultPartition)
---------------------------------------------------------
17:55:53,235 INFO  [DefaultPartition] Number of cluster members: 1
17:55:53,235 INFO  [DefaultPartition] Other members: 0
17:55:53,641 INFO  [PlatformMBeanServerRegistration] JBossCache MBeans were successfully registered to the platform mbean server.
17:55:56,449 INFO  [STDOUT] 
---------------------------------------------------------
GMS: address is 127.0.0.1:55200 (cluster=DefaultPartition-HAPartitionCache)
---------------------------------------------------------
17:55:58,494 INFO  [RPCManagerImpl] Received new cluster view: [127.0.0.1:55200|0] [127.0.0.1:55200]
17:55:58,495 INFO  [RPCManagerImpl] Cache local address is 127.0.0.1:55200
17:55:58,542 INFO  [RPCManagerImpl] state was retrieved successfully (in 2.05 seconds)
17:55:59,010 INFO  [ComponentRegistry] JBoss Cache version: JBossCache 'Malagueta' 3.2.8.GA_JBCACHE_1620
17:55:59,010 INFO  [DefaultPartition] Fetching serviceState (will wait for 30000 milliseconds):
17:56:00,351 INFO  [DefaultPartition] State could not be retrieved (we are the first member in group)
17:56:04,129 INFO  [HANamingService] Started HAJNDI bootstrap; jnpPort=1100, backlog=50, bindAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1
17:56:04,302 INFO  [DetachedHANamingService$AutomaticDiscovery] Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:1102, group=230.0.0.4, HA-JNDI address=127.0.0.1:1100
17:56:21,920 WARN  [JBossASSecurityMetadataStore] WARNING! POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password changed from the installation default. Please see the JBoss Messaging user guide for instructions on how to do this.
17:57:01,259 INFO  [UnifiedInvokerHA] Service name is jboss:service=invoker,type=unifiedha
17:57:32,764 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version - tag:JBOSSTS_4_6_1_GA_CP12) - JBoss Inc.
17:57:32,764 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
17:57:37,070 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Initializing recovery manager
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Cambié a la perspectiva de depuración y observé que la depuración funcionaba, se veían los hilos, pero tras un tiempo se desconectaba, y era el proceso javaw el que marcaba error.

[image: pantallazo]

Ruta del workspace que dejó de funcionar:

```
C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\Downloads\Aplicaciones\TODO-PAO
```

Ruta del workspace que funciona:

```
C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\Downloads\Aplicaciones\TODO-MPCCS
```

Borrando el *error log* antes de correr me da dos errores sin *Stack Trace*.

[image: error log 1]

En el segundo ni siquiera hay descripción del error
[image: error log 2]

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo puedo hacer la depuración en estas condiciones?

ACTUALIZACION

Espero que nadie haya tenido que pasar po la misma penosa situación que yo, todo en mi mente indica que es un eor propio de eclipse y no de configuración. Mi problema surgió cuando estando en modo depuración hubo un corte de corriente y se apagó el PC. Tuve que hacer algo tediosísimo que fue lanzar el sevidor en modo depuración y jugar con la opción de espera por conexiones y conectarme desde netbeans para realizar la depuración en netbeans( lo cual para ser honestos tuvo sus ventajas). Entiendo que la mayoría no contará con tanta RAM como yo en ese momento así que les sugiero en cuanto les sea posible reinstalar su IDE.

Comment: No estás usando debug remoto, no? Quizás podrías intentarlo, a mi personalmente me gusta más.

Comment: De hecho he estado haciendo el debug remoto pero desde netbeans, pero en clases que consultan la BDD no puedo entrar. Parece que deberé realizar el debug remoto para depurar esos casos. Gracias.

Comment: ¿tienes los fuentes de esas clases y no te deja? O_O

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro revisaste que en los dos workspaces uses el mismo jdk? Al estar usando un jboss viejo podrias tener problemas de performance, por ejemplo jboss 7.1  no funciona con java 8 pero si con java 7.

Comment: Uso JBoss EAP 5.1, en ambos casos con JDK 1.6.0_27, y no pude equivocarme de versión, pues con versiones más recientes no levanta. @Robertiano, sí, exactamente la misma configuración.

Comment: Puedes actualizar tu pregunta agregando información de tus dos workspaces, por ejemplo capturas de pantalla de Eclipse en las dos situaciones? También sería bueno conocer las rutas de los dos workspaces, para descartar problemas de espacios en blanco, rutas demasiado largas, etc

Comment: Otra sugerencia: Abre en Eclipse la vista de log de errores (Menú **Window > Show View > Error Log**), tal vez allí encuentres más detalles de lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: OK, queda descartado cualquier problema de caracteres no válidos o longitud de las rutas de los workspaces. Prueba con lo del Error Log a ver cómo te va.

Comment: Listo, no me había dado cuenta de que salían errores.

Answer (score 1):

Has tratado editando tu archivo `messaging-service.xml`

Para evitar problemas con seguridad se debe especificar el valor del atributo `SuckerPassword`

```
 <!-- The password used by the message sucker connections to create connections.
           THIS SHOULD ALWAYS BE CHANGED AT INSTALL TIME TO SECURE SYSTEM    -->
<attribute name="SuckerPassword">4cd5ab1456781b311</attribute>
```

*Algo importante que acabo de recordar es que el valor debe estar [encriptado](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=316).

Comment: y donde encuentro el messaging-service.xml? Gracias

Comment: Hola el path es:  jboss-as/server/all/deploy/messaging/messaging-service.xml trata y me comentas!.

Comment: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User JBM.SUCKER is NOT authenticated :(

Comment: En el otro workspace funciona perfectamente, que configuración creees que se haya movido? Runtime Enviroment por ejemplo?

Answer (score 1):

No sé si lo siguiente puede servir para solucionar el comportamiento anómalo de tu depurador, pero el mensaje de advertencia:

> WARN  [JBossASSecurityMetadataStore] WARNING! POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password changed from the installation default. Please see the JBoss Messaging user guide for instructions on how to do this

Se puede solucionar estableciendo una contraseña para el `MessageSucker` de la siguiente forma:

1. En el archivo `C:\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\all\deploy\messaging\messaging-jboss-beans.xml` debe ir la contraseña
   deseada **en texto plano**.
2. En el archivo `C:\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\all\deploy\messaging\messaging-service.xml` debe ir **la misma contraseña pero encriptada**, mediante la clase `SecurityUtil` de
   JBoss
   La contraseña se encripta así:
   Desde la línea de comandos de Windows, ejecuta `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin\java.exe" -cp C:\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\client\jboss-messaging-client.jar org.jboss.messaging.util.SecurityUtil tu_password_plano`. Como respuesta de la consola, debe aparecer al final lo siguiente

   > Encoded Password: **tu_password_encriptado**

   y esa contraseña generada es la que debes copiar para usar como contraseña en `messaging-service.xml`

Entonces lo que debes configurar en cada archivo xml es:

1. **messaging-jboss-beans.xml**:

   `<property name="suckerPassword">tu_password_plano</property>`
2. **messaging-service.xml**:

   `<attribute name="SuckerPassword">tu_password_encriptado</attribute>`

Después de esto reinicia tu perfil de JBoss.

Comment: Y donde encuentro el `messaging-jboss-beans.xml`? Gracias

Comment: Información adicional sobre las rutas y archivos de configuración en la [Guía de instalación de JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/The_JBoss_Server___A_Quick_Tour.html)

Comment: Creo que avanzó un poco más:

    10:56:07,903 INFO  [DefaultPartition] State could not be retrieved (we are the first member in group)
    10:56:11,841 INFO  [HANamingService] Started HAJNDI bootstrap; jnpPort=1100, backlog=50, bindAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1
    10:56:12,014 INFO  [DetachedHANamingService$AutomaticDiscovery] Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:1102, group=230.0.0.4, HA-JNDI address=127.0.0.1:1100